# How can I use pipe when I need to use the variable name?

Tags: r, magrittr

When using pipe, sometimes I need to use the variables just defined, is it avoidable? like, can I pipe the code in a line? thanks

```
library(magrittr)
A <- c(letters[1:5])
A[which(!A %in% c("a", "b"))]
```

I am looking for a solution like:

```
A <- c(letters[1:5]) %$% .[which(! . %in% c("a","b"))]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you're trying to pull the values out of `A` that aren't `a` or `b` using a pipe, you could use `letters[1:5] %>%  .[!(. %in% c("a", "b"))]`.

Comment: I am not 100% certain either, `A %>% subset(!(. %in% c("a", "b")))` is essentially what @Lyngbakr already suggested.

Comment: sorry, let me clarify the question again.

Comment: Thanks, I should have used ```%in%```

Comment: @Grec001 So, is the question resolved by the given solutions? It helps if you state your expected output explicitly.

Comment: @Lyngbakr for the sample code, I set, yes. I am trying the logic on my work. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `c(letters[1:5])` is identical to `letters[1:5]` ,

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few alternatives.  Note that `%>%`, `extract`, `is_in` and `not` are from magrittr, `fn$` is from gsubfn and `discard` is from purrr.  Everything else is from the base of R.

```
library(magrittr)
A <- letters[1:5]

# 1
A %>% extract(! . %in% c("a", "b"))
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

# 1a
A %>% extract(is_in(.,  c("a", "b") ) %>% not)
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

# 2
A %>% Filter(function(x) ! x %in% c("a", "b"), .)
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

## 2a
library(gsubfn)
A %>% fn$Filter(~ ! x %in% c("a", "b"), .)
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

# 3
A %>% setdiff(c("a", "b"))
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

# 4
A %>% grep("^(a|b)$", ., invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## [1] "c" "d" "e"

# 5
library(purrr)
A %>% discard(~ . %in% c("a", "b"))
## [1] "c" "d" "e"
```

Also see comments under question for additional alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Direct function with pipe will be :

```
A %>% .[which(A!=c("a", "b"))]
```

because a function to pipe is []
Also you can try to use function `match()` or `%in%` instead `A!=c("a", "b")` in that case `Negate('%in%')`

I cannot comment but to discussion - use a fact that is functional language.

```
subset_pipe <- function(x, y) {x %>% .[!x %in% y] }
letters[1:5] %>% subset_pipe(c("b", "z"))
```

Comment: Your logical comparison produces and element-wise comparison that will recycle the comparison values "a" and "b". This produces a warning (try running `letters[1:5] != c('a','b')`) and is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @jdobres  Yes that is true. 
It will not give warning, but I think in that moment question is differed. In fist version was != that is why is suggest %in% or negation as more suited because I thought will be better approach for list. 
Now in question is %in% which is a same. 
You can use with negation 
`subset_pipe <- function(x, y) {x %>% .[!x %in% y] }` 

`> A[which(!A %in% c("a", "b"))]` 
`[1] "c" "d" "e"` 
`> A %>% subset_pipe( c("a", "b"))`
`[1] "c" "d" "e"`
or I missing something.